# Fresh install Laravel 5.1 and get server 500

Tags: apache, installation, laravel-5.1

i install Laravel 5.1 via composer set premissions for /storage and /bootstrap/cache and create vhost in sites-enable/project.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.sklad.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sklad/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/sklad/public>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>


# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

in /public/.htaccess i have :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i enabled revrite mod on apache2 and restart apache.But i still have Server not found 500. Do you have some ides what can be wrong? And the log from apache is :

```
[Thu Feb 25 23:14:44.838725 2016] [:error] [pid 2505] [client 127.0.0.1:37241] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/html/sklad/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(202): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4 /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(113): Illuminate\\Log\\Writer- in /var/www/html/sklad/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87
```

Comment: Why not check the error log? What server are you running? The logs are usually stored in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for Linux servers.

Comment: i edit my question and add apache log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't set the permissions up quite right for `/storage`. It is trying to write an error to the log, but doesn't have permission to create or write to the log.

To change this just make sure you are setting your permissions recursively:

`sudo chmod -R 777 /storage`

Setting permissions to `777` can pose its risks though, so use a permission level that you are comfortable with, perhaps `775` as that would let Laravel read and write to the log files.

You may want to recheck all of your permissions to your other folders to make sure you have set them recursively.

Comment: Thank i forget for this :) Thanks